# How to use RestClientException catch in Android

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have one Rest Web Service and I am using this web service from the below code of android.

The web service is working fine I have test that.

But in the below code I am getting error

```
  String url ="http://10.0.2.2:29512/Restweb_2/webresources/generic/shirish";

  RestTemplate resttemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Log.v("in1", "in1");
 resttemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    Log.v("in2", "in2");
   String result;
        try {            
            result = resttemplate.getForObject(url,String.class);
        } 
        catch (RestClientException ex) {
           ![I am getting this error while using this exception and I am not able to proceed further if I don't use this exception(Or it is giving me error in result assign statment)][1]. So how to use RestClient!Exception ????? Also I already import the needed jar files.

        }
```

Comment: You need help in removing or handling the `RestClientException`?

Comment: But if i remove the exception then the line " result = resttemplate.getForObject(url,String.class);  " is giving me the error must be sorrounded by the try-catch block and ordinary try catch is also giving the same error. So  it must be catch with RestClientException .

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `RestClientException` will be thrown by `RestTemplate` whenever it encounters client-side HTTP errors. Now what is your expectation?

Comment: Sorry first of all. I just want to use RestClientException in Catch clause but it is giving me the error when I write catch(RestClientException  ex) error :- incompatible type required throwable found RestClientException.                                          .                                                                            .                                                                     So I want to use restclientexception in my catch clause anyways .     Is it clear or should I elaborate more?

Comment: Check whether the class `RestClientException` implements `Throwable` in the version of the jar you've got.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: My jar file don't implement Throwable for the RestClientException. So i add file that has throwable.  Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

> incompatible type required throwable found RestClientException

This can be caused when you've included the spring-android-rest-template-xxxx.jar and haven't included the spring-android-core-xxxx.jar

Comment: spring-android-core jar can be downloaded from here- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.android/spring-android-core/1.0.0.RELEASE